# disassemble code from c#

Tags: c#, build, disassembly

In connection with improving my build and deploy routines I wish to compare the code of two different assemblies. I cannot compare filesize and created date, or the binary content of the assemblies as these might differ even if the assemblies are logically identical.

In previous projects I have used ildasm.exe and produced a text file for each assembly, and compared these after slight modifications, but I would rather do this in c# code without running Process.Start().

As example I wish to do something like this:

```
public bool AssemblyComparer(string path1, string path2)
{  
  var text1 = MagicLibrary.Disassemble(path1);
  var text2 = MagicLibrary.Disassemble(path2);
  return text1.Equals(text2);
}
```

Any suggestions as to how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: `binary content of the assemblies as these might differ even if the assemblies are logically identical.` I didn't get this?

Comment: Whole word is using versions. Why do you want to compare content?

Comment: The binary content contains timestamp of when the assembly was compiled, so even if they are logically identical, they don't have the same checksum.

Comment: Lets say a build produces assemblies A,B and C. A user checks in changes to assembly A, but B and C are still built. So if I want to make the least possible impact on the environments I deploy to, I just want to deploy assembly A. To find out if B and C are different from the assemblies allready deployed, I cannot use binary comparison because technically there are different assemblies build on different times. But deploying them will be a waste of resources as they dont represent a change.

Comment: @Sinatr versions makes no sense when working with multiple branches. v3.1 might be older or newer than v3.1 in a different branch.

Comment: You can't have *same* version for different files. That's the whole point: version should identify content. If you create branches, then reserve for each subset of versions. In my software versions sometimes are weird, like "MySoftware.1.4.0.10a10a11", but they are unique.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it but as far as I know Mono.Cecil is a library with which you can inspect IL code in your programs from assemblies. See [Mono.Cecil by jbevain](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil). But I don't think it's as easy to use as you would like it in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into that. I added the snippet to clarify my purpose. I'm sure I can handle slightly more complex code :)

Comment: @Snorre Didn't want to imply you couldn't :)